# What type of lightbulb fits this lamp?

Tags: light-bulb

[image: lamp]

I recently purchased this lamp and I can't find the type of bulb it needs. The shade is a glass globe with a 1.5 inch opening also.

Comment: Some version of bi-pin - probably originally halogen, can get LEDs as well now, exactly which would depend on exactly what size the opening is and what the pin contact spacing is.

Comment: Did the instructions say what kind of bulb to use? Odds are good that they did...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably **G9**. Socket:

[image]

Bulb:

[image]